# how to compress and uncompress a text file

Tags: c#

I am having two problems

My problems are

1. My file name is  20110505.txt  , and  it is compressing a zip file name as  ->   20110505.txt.zip
   But I need  after compressing   this  file   20110505.txt   as -->    20110505.zip only.

I am using this dll

using System.IO.Compression;

Here is my code for compress,

1)is my text format

```
            string path = DayDestination + "\\" + txtSelectedDate.Text + ".txt";
            StreamWriter Strwriter = new StreamWriter(path);
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(path);
            Compress(fi);

   public static void Compress(FileInfo fi) 
{ 
    // Get the stream of the source file. 
    using (FileStream inFile = fi.OpenRead()) 
    {

        // Prevent compressing hidden and already compressed files. 
        if ((File.GetAttributes(fi.FullName) & FileAttributes.Hidden) 
                != FileAttributes.Hidden & fi.Name != ".zip") 
        { 
            // Create the compressed file. 
           using (FileStream outFile = File.Create(fi.FullName + ".zip"))

            //using (FileStream outFile = File.Create( fi.Name+ ".zip")) 
            { 
                using (GZipStream Compress = new GZipStream(outFile, 
                        CompressionMode.Compress)) 
                { 
                    // Copy the source file into the compression stream. 
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096]; 
                    int numRead; 
                    while ((numRead = inFile.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0) 
                    { 
                        Compress.Write(buffer, 0, numRead); 
                    } 
                    Console.WriteLine("Compressed {0} from {1} to {2} bytes.", 
                        fi.Name, fi.Length.ToString(), outFile.Length.ToString()); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

1. If my zip file name is  20110505.zip  after uncompressing i want my file name to be 20110505.txt  . after uncomressing the zip file to text file i want to delete the zip file after compressing

   ```
     string Path2 = (string)(Application.StartupPath + "\\TEMP\\" + "\\" + name_atoz);

     DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Path2);
     FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Path2);
     Compress(fi);

     public static void Decompress(FileInfo fi) 
     { 
           // Get the stream of the source file. 
           using (FileStream inFile = fi.OpenRead()) 
           { 
               // Get original file extension, for example "doc" from report.doc.gz. 
               string curFile = fi.FullName; 
               string origName = curFile.Remove(curFile.Length - fi.Extension.Length); 

               //Create the decompressed file. 
               using (FileStream outFile = File.Create(origName)) 
               { 
                   using (GZipStream Decompress = new GZipStream(inFile, 
                           CompressionMode.Decompress)) 
                   { 
                       //Copy the decompression stream into the output file. 
                       byte[] buffer = new byte[4096]; 
                       int numRead; 
                       while ((numRead = Decompress.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0) 
                       { 
                           outFile.Write(buffer, 0, numRead); 
                       } 
                       Console.WriteLine("Decompressed: {0}", fi.Name); 

                   } 
               } 
           } 
       }
   ```

I want this because i am creating a project which reads the text file .

Is there any suggestion for my problem.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: see Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to uncompress zip file into a text extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243113/how-to-uncompress-zip-file-into-a-text-extension)

Answer (score 2):

As Mitch pointed out in the comments above, the problem seems to be with your file name being used for the zip file.  You include the FullName, but that has the .txt at the end.  Trim that off and you should have what you want.

The line I'm talking about is this one:

```
using (FileStream outFile = File.Create(fi.FullName + ".zip"))
```

A simple way to fix it would be as follows:

```
using (FileStream outFile = File.Create(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(fi.FullName, ".txt$", "") + ".zip"))
```

To delete your zip file after you decompress it, put the following line in your `Decompress` method as the very last line (outside your outer-most using statement):

```
File.Delete(fi);
```

You probably want to wrap that in a try-catch but this is the basic code to run.  Here is an article on how to delete a file safely:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/file-delete

Comment: if i trim the text file the streamwriter creates a file which is not a text file

Comment: @G Basha - my edit shows you a bit more explicitly what I was talking about.  This won't affect the text file that is being created.  This makes the edit only on the zip file's name when it is being created.

Comment: i am getting an error the error is on fi.FullName.TrimEnd(".txt")       the error is    The best overloaded method match for 'string.TrimEnd(params char[])' has some invalid arguments      using (FileStream outFile = File.Create(fi.FullName.TrimEnd(".txt") + ".zip")) can u pls help me

Comment: @G Basha - Sorry, my bad on that.  I forgot that TrimEnd takes a char, not a string.  I've updated my code to use RegEx instead.  The dollar sign represents the end of the string.  This should work for you.

Comment: Thank You very much its working can u pls say me how to delete the zip file after unzipping

Comment: @G Basha - I added how to delete the file to my post.