# how to uncompress zip file into a text extension

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [how to read a *.file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241986/how-to-read-a-file)
>   [how to compress and uncompress a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241188/how-to-compress-and-uncompress-a-text-file)

Hi,

I am having a problem in uncompressing the zip file into a text file,

when i compress the text file into a zip file (Ex-20110530.txt to 20110530.zip) .my code is compressing the code i use for compressing the text file to a zip file is

```
       string path = (string)(Application.StartupPath + "\\TEMP\\TEMP_BACKFILL_atoz" + "\\" + name_atoz);
       StreamWriter Strwriter = new StreamWriter(path);
       DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
       FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(path);
       Compress(fi);

public static void Compress(FileInfo fi) 
{ 
    // Get the stream of the source file. 
    using (FileStream inFile = fi.OpenRead()) 
    {

        // Prevent compressing hidden and already compressed files. 
        if ((File.GetAttributes(fi.FullName) & FileAttributes.Hidden) 
                != FileAttributes.Hidden & fi.Name != ".zip") 
        { 
            // Create the compressed file. 
           using (FileStream outFile = File.Create(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(fi.FullName, ".txt$", "") + ".zip"))

            { 
                using (GZipStream Compress = new GZipStream(outFile, 
                        CompressionMode.Compress)) 
                { 
                    // Copy the source file into the compression stream. 
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096]; 
                    int numRead; 
                    while ((numRead = inFile.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0) 
                    { 
                        Compress.Write(buffer, 0, numRead); 
                    } 
                    Console.WriteLine("Compressed {0} from {1} to {2} bytes.", 
                        fi.Name, fi.Length.ToString(), outFile.Length.ToString()); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

this code creates a zip file when i unzip the file it creates a file called 20110530 not a 20110530.txt .

I want the file to be uncompress with 20110530.txt format

the code i use to uncompress the file is

```
    public static void Decompress(FileInfo fi)
    {
        // Get the stream of the source file. 
        using (FileStream inFile = fi.OpenRead())
        {
            // Get original file extension, for example "doc" from report.doc.gz. 
            string curFile = fi.FullName;
            string origName = curFile.Remove(curFile.Length - fi.Extension.Length);

            //Create the decompressed file. 
            using (FileStream outFile = File.Create(origName))
            {
                using (GZipStream Decompress = new GZipStream(inFile,
                        CompressionMode.Decompress))
                {
                    //Copy the decompression stream into the output file. 
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                    int numRead;
                    while ((numRead = Decompress.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                    {
                        outFile.Write(buffer, 0, numRead);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Decompressed: {0}", fi.Name);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Can Anyone Pls Help Me,

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Apparently, you didn't write this code. Have you read the comments in the decompression code?

Comment: It's getting better but you should add code to the existing question, not post a new one.

Comment: You've asked the same question 3 times. Please desist!

Comment: what i should do no if they give 1 answer i will get 2 problems

Comment: @G Basha: Then perhaps the answers are not the best possible. Another possibility is that they are answers to what you asked, not what you intended to ask...

Answer (score 3):

Seems to me that this line:

```
string origName = curFile.Remove(curFile.Length - fi.Extension.Length);
```

Removes the extension from the string, but you use that line when creating the uncompressed stream.

```
using (FileStream outFile = File.Create(origName))
```

Instead, use this:

```
using (FileStream outFile = File.Create(origName + ".txt"))
```

and that should create the uncompressed file with a `TXT` extension.

Comment: However, that only adds the extension `.txt`, not the original extension, so it only works when the original extension actually was `.txt`.

Comment: @Guffa - Completely true, but I just shows the `txt` extension as that's what he specifically wanted.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you remove the extension when you compress the file so that it becomes `20110530.zip` instead of `20110530.txt.zip`. The code that decompresses the file uses everything before `.zip` as file name, so naturally you end up with `20110530` instead of `20110530.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to include the original file extension when you create a file in **Decompress**

```
//Create the decompressed file. 
using (FileStream outFile = File.Create(origName)) // <<<-- here
```